# Truck driver looking to get fit

Tags: workout-routines, workout, upper-body-workout, workout-types

I'm a team driver, and I'm trying to get fit I have changed my eating habits but I feel I really need to work out. I wanted to know what are some good work outs to do in my sleeper?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what, if anything, you have available to assist you in working out.  Also, what are your limitations: space, time, etc.?

Comment: I would reccomend bodyweight excercises and/or sling training. You can attach the sling trainer to you truck (attach it to the door, a ladder or the trainler) and work out with this. Sling trainers would be affordable from expensive (300 $ for a TRX) to very cheap (20$ self made or 40 $ Ebay). For bodyweight excercises, there are a lot of resources out there. See e.g. my posts http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25863/working-out-at-the-playground/25871#25871

Comment: Ways to improve your question:  Are you wanting to do exercises inside the vehicle? _("...workouts to do **in** my sleeper")_  What kind of schedule is available to you - how often do you take breaks and for how long?  Are you able to safely/comfortably work out in the immediate vicinity of your vehicle when you are stopped?  (Empty parking lots in the sunshine vs. pulled off on an on ramp in a snowstorm.)  "Get fit" means what to you?  Strength?  Weight loss?  Less huffing and puffing in daily tasks?  Where are you starting?  (Height/Weight/fitness level)